# Processing in AudioRecord thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audiorecord

I am processing audio recorded by AudioRecord in a thread, but if I run the processing in the recorder thread, some frames get dropped. According to [android, AudioRecord.read() --> bufferoverflow, how to handle the buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218856/android-audiorecord-read-bufferoverflow-how-to-handle-the-buffer), I need to run the processing in a separate thread, but how? Do I need to create a new thread for every single frame (2-3 per second)?

Here is my current solution but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

```
//in the AudioRecord thread
while (!break_condition) {
    int num_read = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    HeavyProcessingRunnable myRunnable = new HeavyProcessingRunnable(buffer);
    Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable)
    t.start();
}
```

The runnable for the heavy processing

```
public class HeavyProcessingRunnable implements Runnable {
    private byte[] var;
    public HeavyProcessingRunnable(byte[] var) {
        this.var = var;
    }
    public void run() {
        //if this is executed in audio recorder thread, frames get dropped
        someHeavyProcessing(var);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you finally solve this problem? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new thread everytime is somewhat expensive [(discussion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive). It would be better to create the heavy processing thread only once and feed it with audio samples. Here's an example:

```java
// Do it only once.

HandlerThread myHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("my-handler-thread");
myHandlerThread.start();

Handler myHandler = new Handler(myHandlerThread.getLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        someHeavyProcessing((byte[]) msg.obj, msg.arg1);
        return true;
    }
});

// In audio recorder thread.
// Mind the handler reference.

while (!break_condition) {
    int num_read = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    Message message = myHandler.obtainMessage();
    message.obj = buffer;
    message.arg1 = num_read;
    message.sendToTarget();
}
```

By the way, it's important to provide `num_read` along with the audio samples.

Comment: @user09123789542 for checking the number of bytes read (>= 0) or any error code (< 0). `read()` may read less bytes than the buffer size [(documentation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)).